# Is it okay to have the identity and app context in my application point to the same database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2

I have an ASP.Net WebAPI application. There are currently two SQL Server databases:

```
identity database - holds all the Identity tables
app      database - holds all the application tables
```

I have two contexts and everything works okay.

I would like to combine the tables from the two databases. To put the identity tables into the app database.

Can I still have two contexts and just recreate the tables in the app database and point the connection string of the identity context and the app context to the same database?

Comment: Absolutely. However, why have two connection pools when you only need one? Are both databases currently hosted on the same machine?

Comment: @gknicker - Yes they are currently on the same machine. I am a bit confused. Can I combine the two contexts into one or should I keep two contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go further and have only one DbContext instead of 2. This will make everything easier and less code to maintain.

Comment: I'm about to ask "how to do this".

Answer (score 1):

> Can I still have two contexts and just recreate the tables in the app database and point the connection string of the identity context and the app context to the same database?

Yes, it's fine to have two contexts pointing to the same database. Since the two databases are already hosted on the same machine, you should combine them.

And once that's working, you may as well have only one connection string in your web.config also, if possible.

[Keep it simple](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?KeepItSimple) is a good idea, wherever it makes sense to do so. By the way, that link takes you to the first ever wiki :)